# RestTemplate usage

Tags: java, http, curl, put, resttemplate

I'm trying to use `RestTemplate` in order to make a `PUT`. For some reason I can't reproduce the `PUT` I created using `curl` that goes through without any problems.

Here is my `curl` call that succeeds and returns 200:

```
curl https://www.exampe.com \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <bearer-token>" \
  -v \
  -d '{"json":"object"}'
```

And here is Java code that tried to replicate this `curl` call. This code in my case will throw `HttpClientErrorException` with status = 406:

```
boolean result = false; 
String url = "https://www.example.com";
String json = "{\"json\":\"object\"}";

RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.add("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", authToken));

HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(json, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = 
        rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class);

HttpStatus status = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
```

What's the difference between these requests? How do I converge the Java version to the `curl` version?

Comment: http://garciapl.blogspot.com/2012/09/spring-rest-template-with-ssl.html

Comment: Adding just that snipped doesn't seem to help. Is there anything else I should look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agghr, so stupid. the missing part was the `Accept` header. Apparently `curl` adds `Accept: */*` by default. It's probably the endpoint implementation that expected proper `Accept` header. Adding this line solved the problem:

```
headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
```