# Having trouble recreating a cURL command in a Spring RestTemplate Using Headers

Tags: spring, curl, resttemplate

Here's the curl command I'm trying to recreate :

```
curl https://bannana-pajamas.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=BananaQuery -H 'Authorization: Bearer Banana_Token'
```

This curl command works just fine in my terminal and returns a json file.

Here's my attempt at recreating it in a Spring Rest Template:

```
//Create a rest template
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

        System.out.println("This here is the token "+Banana_Token);


        //Create the headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization","Bearer "+Banana_Token);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        //Create the url
        String url = "https://bannana-pajamas.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=BananaQuery";

        String response;

        try{
            response = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).toString();
        }catch(Exception error){
            System.out.println("This still ain't working bro. Imma make this null till you get stuff right");
            response = null;
        }


        return response;
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

I've tried several of the similar answers on this site, but I keep getting that error. I probably missing something very minor.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: may be try url like this without the tailing slash https://bannana-pajamas.com/services/data/v20.0/query?q=BananaQuery

Comment: I'm assuming you meant without the https? I tried that and it didn't work. Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: no keep the https just get rid of trailing slash before the query param. Alternatively you can also try rest.exchange("https://bannana-pajamas.com/services/data/v20.0/query?q={name}", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, "BananaQuery");

Comment: I got the same error after removing the slash.

Comment: try adding `headers.add("Accept", "*/*");` since curl is auto adding it by default. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107494/resttemplate-usage for further information. I just realized you get a 400 so I think it's not related anyway. Nevermind...

Comment: I'll give that a shot as well. I'm currently trying a super dirty method using processbuilder and curl.